# How do you delete an AWS EMR Cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

I've been playing around with AWS EMR and I now have a few clusters that are terminated and that I want to delete:

[image]

However, there is no obvious option to delete them. How do I make them go away?

Comment: If they are terminated, they will go away by themselves later.

Comment: When is later? I have one since 2015-10-31...

Comment: I've found that sometimes you have to delete from the command line. I'm assuming that you have already read this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_TerminateJobFlow.html but have you tried from the AWS CLI? Maybe termination protection is enabled?

Comment: When termination protection is enabled, you can't terminate the machines. It has nothing to do with deleting. @vy32 did you check your EC2 console if the terminated machines are still there?

Comment: Thanks for your note. If you look above, the status of the clusters is that they are terminated.  They are just still on the control panel. I guess they stay around so that you can clone them, even after they are terminated.

Comment: they will be cleaned from the list auto within two weeks, I think they already missing now.

Comment: Well, they are still there, even after a month.

Comment: If I remember correctly, they stay in the console for about 60 days. You can only avoid the noise using 'Active clusters' filter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They stay around for 60 days which is now documented here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-view-clusters.html

> Amazon EMR saves metadata about terminated clusters for your reference for two months, after which the metadata is deleted.

Answer (score 15):

They will stay around for a while and will be automatically deleted later. There is apparently no fixed time documented anywhere.